# What's the different between ceramic and steel bearing

Tags: frames, ceramic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Real measurable benefit to ceramic bearings?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5319/real-measurable-benefit-to-ceramic-bearings)

What's the different between ceramic and steel bearing ?
On the bottom bracket, what do you feel when you change into ceramic bearing ?
is it better then steel on BB7800 ?

Better power transfer ? if it's almost the same, not worth the money then ??
thanks a lot

Comment: Several hundred dollars and bragging rights.  (There was an earlier thread that went over the topic pretty well, and, IIRC, the net is that ceramic bearings do reduce rolling resistance, but probably not enough to notice.)

Comment: Here's the prior thread: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5319/real-measurable-benefit-to-ceramic-bearings

Comment: If the answers to that question don't really answer what you want, please feel free to edit this question to clarify and flag it and I'll reopen.